# Positioning of image within an equation

Tags: graphics, equations, positioning

I have the following problem: I would like to have images of Feynman diagrams as part of equations. Using

```
\newcommand{\imineq}[2]{
\includegraphics[height=#2ex]{#1}}
```

I had success in as far as

```
\begin{equation}
H\left(\imineq{Feynman_image}{7}\right)=
\end{equation}
```

does put the image roughly where it's meant to be but shifted upwards to the top half of the brackets. Anyone have any ideas as to how I can get the image to appear vertically centered and ideally get the brackets to scale properly?

Comment: You can use `\raisebox{-2ex}{\includegraphics...}` to adjust the position, or perhaps simpler use the adjustbox package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In math mode there is the command `\vcenter` which will center material vertically.  So you can set up your command as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\imineq}[2]{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=#2ex]{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\( a \left( \imineq{example-image-a}{4} \right) b \)

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adjusting it manually, you can use `\raisebox`. But I'm not sure this is the best way. `\vcenter` might be an option. You might have to put the image in an hbox to use use this.

As far as the brackets goes, I would manually specify the size you want, e.g. `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`.

A more satisfying answer might be to use TikZ which gives you a great deal of power for positioning such things. Here is [an example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11105/tikz-diagrams-in-math-mode) of someone doing something similar.