# Create similar triangles symbol

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

In my country, the similar triangle symbol is different to `\cong` or `\sim` symbol.
I draw the symbol with TikZ package so it is not compatible with sizes and color.
Please help me create the symbol with TeX command.
Thank you very much.

[image]

P.S The code draws similar symbol.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-7pt,scale=0.1,line width=0.65pt]

\draw (-2,0);
\draw (4,0);
\draw (0,0) arc (90:270:1)..controls +(0:1) and +(180:1).. (2,0) arc (90:-90:1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The curve is no doubt aesthetic-- with minimal and complete arcs and curves connected smoothly. However, I'm a bit curious to know (nothing related to LaTeX, though) in _which country_ a pair of similar triangles are denoted by a symbol having nothing to do with straight lines even !

Comment: @ParthaD. I live in VietNam.

Comment: That's wonderful. Tôi rất thích nó !

Comment: @ParthaD. I’m guessing, rotated S for *sembables*? (Without going into that history.)

Comment: @Davislor Yes, that's a good catch at linguistic etymology. _Similar_ and _semblance_ all start with *S*, whose colloquial form could be `\sim` (how come I never wondered before !) and more puritan form the rotated "S".  Nice !

Comment: hey just paste this symbol. it works. ∽

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you like your tikz symbol there is another simple option. You can wrap it inside a macro and use scalable units. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {tikz}

\newcommand{\similar}
{%
  \mathrel%
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.south),line width=0.15ex]
      \node (a) {};
      \draw (0,0.5ex) arc (90:270:0.5ex) .. controls +(0:0.5ex) and +(180:0.5ex) .. (1ex,0.5ex) arc (90:-90:0.5ex);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

\begin{document}
The red triangles {\color{red} $ABC \similar DEF$} are similar.

So are the big triangles {\large $A'B'C' \similar  D'E'F'$}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** As Davislor suggested I wrapped all in a `\mathrel` for a better spacing.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: It is equal to the original. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano, thanks!!. Yes it's the same, I only changed the units and wrapped it inside a macro.

Comment: The technique is scalable ex unit.
It is not equal to the original code.
Juan Castaño's code is quite good!

Comment: Like I mentioned at the end of my answer, you want to wrap it in `\mathrel` for correct spacing.

Comment: @Davislor, you are right. I made an edit and added the `\mathrel`. It looks better :-)

Answer (score 6):

∽ (U+223D) is `\backsim` in the packages `unicode-math`, `stix` or `stix2`.

You could instead put a sans-serif S inside a `\rotatebox` from `graphicx`.

You can also put a tikzpicture inside `\mathrel` and [use it as a relation symbol in math mode.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11105/tikz-diagrams-in-math-mode)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! 
The second option is useful!
https://ibb.co/fxRGhxL