# How do I put math mode inside a TikZ picture inside math mode?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, standalone

I have the following code for an equation using TikZ pictures.

```latex
\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert={outext=.svg,command=\unexpanded{pdf2svg \infile\space\outfile}},multi=false]{standalone}[2012/04/13]
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\Hask{\mathsf{Hask}}
\def\Id{\mathsf{Id}}
\def\T{\mathsf{T}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
    \node (H1) {$\Hask$};
    \node (H2) [right of= H1] {$\Hask$};
    \draw[->, bend left] (H1) to node[above] {$\Id_{\Hask}$} (H2);
    \draw[->, bend right] (H1) to node[below] {$\T$} (H2);
  \end{tikzpicture} =
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
    \node (H1) {$\Hask$};
    \node (H2) [right of= H1] {$\Hask$};
    \draw[->, bend left] (H1) to node[above] {$\Id_{\Hask}$} (H2);
    \draw[->, bend right] (H1) to node[below] {$\T$} (H2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I.e., note the use of in-line math in the text nodes. Unfortunately it does not work, and yields the following errors:

```
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.28   \end{tikzpicture}
                         =
? 
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.28   \end{tikzpicture}
                         =
? 
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.28   \end{tikzpicture}
                         =
? 
[1]

! LaTeX Error: \begin{equation*} on input line 22 ended by \end{tikzpicture}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.28   \end{tikzpicture}
                         =
? 

Overfull \hbox (22.7778pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--34
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 = 

Overfull \vbox (3.66875pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[2{/usr/local/share/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
}] [3]

! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.35 \end{equation*}
                    
? 
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{equation*}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.35 \end{equation*}
                    
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.35 \end{equation*}
                    
? 
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \endgroup 
l.35 \end{equation*}
                    
? 
! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 
                          
l.35 \end{equation*}
                    
? 
[4] (./monadUnit.aux) )</usr/local/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss1
0.pfb></usr/local/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss8.pfb>
Output written on monadUnit.pdf (4 pages, 24416 bytes).
Transcript written on monadUnit.log.
system returned with code 256

Class standalone:
Output written on monadUnit.svg.
 ) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on monadUnit.log.
```

So what is the trick to make this work?

A related question was asked here before [TikZ Diagrams in Math Mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11105/tikz-diagrams-in-math-mode) but for the math mode text in the nodes.

### Addendum

The solution provided by @gernot works for me, provided we define `multi={equation*}` in the document class declaration. This is needed to get correctly cropped output.

Comment: your fragment is fine in normal classes the error is an artifact of `standalone` processing

Comment: Unrelated: Add the option `baseline=(H1.base)` to the two tikzpictures, to align the pictures with the equality sign

Comment: Lovely. Thank you for that. Which makes me wonder, why does it not work normally with `standalone`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David pointed out in the comments, the problem is the result of using the `standalone` class. So one solution is to use another document class.

If you are bound to use `standalone`, you can use a `\savebox`:

- Define a savebox, e.g. one called `\mypic`.

  ```
  \newsavebox\mypic
  ```
- Save the picture into the box:

  ```
  \savebox\mypic{\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}
  ```
- Use the box, also in difficult contexts like the equation in `standalone`:

  ```
  \begin{equation*}
    \usebox\mypic = \usebox\mypic
  \end{equation*}
  ```

[image]

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert={outext=.svg,command=\unexpanded{pdf3svg \infile\space\outfile}},multi=false]{standalone}[2012/04/13]
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\Hask{\mathsf{Hask}}
\def\Id{\mathsf{Id}}
\def\T{\mathsf{T}}

\newsavebox\mypic
\savebox\mypic{\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
    \node (H1) {$\Hask$};
    \node (H2) [right of= H1] {$\Hask$};
    \draw[->, bend left] (H1) to node[above] {$\Id_{\Hask}$} (H2);
    \draw[->, bend right] (H1) to node[below] {$\T$} (H2);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \usebox\mypic = \usebox\mypic
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very nice and compiles without error. But now I had to change the `multi` option to `{equation*}` to get correctly cropped output. This does produce the output I expect, but also throws an error: ```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.22 \end{equation}
                  ``` Any idea how that can be fixed?

Comment: I do need to use `standalone` for cropping and the output conversion to SVG. Any idea why this problem arises?

Comment: @6d03 This is a problem of `standalone` with `crop` and the `equation` environment and is unrelated to `tikz`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50171/110998 for a discussion of this problem, with workarounds (e.g., use `\(...\)` instead of the `equation` environment, maybe with `\displaystyle`.

Comment: Thanks @gernot. It turns out cleaning aux files and rerunning the build fixed it.